# CommandLink action redirect to external url not working

Tags: jsf-2

I am using jsf 2. I have a link in a facelet file that points to a external url. My current view is /app1/home.xhtml with a h:commandLink that has an action like so

```
<h:commandLink value="#{link}" action="#{action.redirect}" target="_blank"/>
```

the url that action.redirect redirects to is /app2/info.do. However it appears that JSF tries to change the extension of the url to .xhtml. and then fails with the error message.

com.sun.faces.context.FacesFileNotFoundException: /app2/info.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

how do i get this to correctly redirect ?

Answer (score 6):

Don't use the [`<h:commandLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html) here, it's the wrong tag for the purpose. It is designed to submit a JSF POST form and navigate to a JSF view, both which you obviously don't want to let take place in this particular use case.

Just use the [`<h:outputLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputLink.html) or even plain HTML `<a>`. So,

```
<h:outputLink value="#{action.redirect}" target="_blank">#{link}</h:outputLink>
```

or

```
<a href="#{action.redirect}" target="_blank">#{link}</a>
```

Note that you don't need the `<h:form>` in both approaches.

Comment: perhaps i did not explain this correctly. the action.redirect() method is what actually does the redirect by calling FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(redirectURL); The redirectURL needs to be computed proramatically. h:outputLink will therefore not work.

Comment: That should just work and not result in the described problem symptom. Your concrete problem is likely caused elsewhere or you misinterpreted the concrete problem.

Comment: Well i dont know about that. I noticed that if works with a:commandLink for whatever reason. but not sure how to open the in new window a:commandLink

Comment: what I forgot to mention was that i use weld and i know that weld has a similar documented issue - https://community.jboss.org/message/759314#759314. So maybe in this case weld is what is causing the change in extension from .do to .xhmtl